# Better way of checking if a file do not exist in a directory

Tags: java

I am trying to run a reconciliation job where I need to read input string from a (huge) file and need to validate if a specific directory has a file whose filename starts with input string or not. The directory(ies) is/are massive and can contain up to 800,000 files. Considering this, I am using `File[] directoryListing` just once and then I am iterating the input file's lines against it. Here is the code:

```
public class CheckForFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirPath = "W:\\ThePath\\ToThe\\Directory";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (dir.isDirectory() && dir.exists()) {
            File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
            String line;
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.csv"))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strArray = line.split(",", -1);
                    System.out.println(fileExistsInDir(strArray[0], directoryListing));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(dirPath + " - is not a Directory.. ");
        }

    }

    public static String fileExistsInDir(String fileNameStartsWithStr, File[] directoryListing) {
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                if (child.isFile()) {
                    if (child.getName().startsWith(fileNameStartsWithStr)) {
                    } else {
                        return "file DO NOT exist for - " + fileNameStartsWithStr;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("directoryListing empty...");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am checking which file is missing against the entry in input.csv file. Above code works Okay. But since its a remote windows share directory path it takes a while to get the list of files. Is there a better way of doing all this? The ask here is to see `file DO NOT exist for - foobar` in the console. Any suggestions/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Only a few files are missing in the directory but are listed in the input.csv.

Problem Statement:
Need to find out which files are missing in the directory against that list.

Update2:
Per DuncG's solution I tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.csv"))) {
            Set<String> scanfor = lines
                    .map(line -> line.split(",", -1))
                    .filter(line -> line.length > 0)
                    .map(line -> line[0])
                    .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            System.out.println("scanfor size: " + scanfor.size());

            try (Stream<Path> scan = Files.find(Paths.get("W:\\ThePath\\ToThe\\Directory"),
                    1, (p, a) -> !a.isDirectory() && !matches(p.getFileName().toString(), scanfor))) {

                long count = scan.peek(System.out::println).count();

                System.out.println("Number of files not matching CSV criteria: " + count);
            }
        }
        
        Instant finish = Instant.now();
        long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMinutes();
        
        System.out.println("Total time consumed :"+ timeElapsed );
    }

    private static boolean matches(String fn, Set<String> scanfor) {
        // Search by exact match in the set
        for (int i = fn.length(); i >= 1; i--) {
            if (scanfor.contains(fn.substring(0, i)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I started with half of the file records. My console is showing: `scanfor size: 472948`. Now it seems to be running forever and its been more than 30 minutes I am waiting for it to end. What might be wrong here?

Update3:

I tried this as suggested by DuncG:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Instant start = Instant.now();

        System.out.println(start);

        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.csv"))) {
            Set<String> scanfor = lines.map(line -> line.split(",", -1)).filter(line -> line.length > 0)
                    .map(line -> line[0]).filter(s -> s.length() > 0).collect(Collectors.toSet());

            IntSummaryStatistics stats = scanfor.stream().mapToInt(String::length).summaryStatistics();
            System.out.println("scanfor stats: " + stats);

            Path out = Paths.get("app.log");

            try (BufferedWriter os = Files.newBufferedWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                    Stream<Path> scan = Files.find(
                            Paths.get("W:\\ThePath\\ToThe\\Directory"), 1,
                            (p, a) -> !a.isDirectory() && !matches(p.getFileName().toString(), scanfor, stats))) {

                scan.map(Path::toString).forEach(s -> write(os, s));
            }
            System.out.println("saved as: " + out);
        }

        Instant finish = Instant.now();

        System.out.println(finish);

        long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMinutes();

        System.out.println("Total time consumed in Minutes :" + timeElapsed);

    }

    private static void write(BufferedWriter wr, String s) {
        try {
            wr.write(s);
            wr.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    private static boolean matches(String fn, Set<String> scanfor, IntSummaryStatistics stats) {
        // Can search by exact match in the set knowing the smallest/largest string of
        // scanfor
        for (int i = stats.getMin(), max = Math.min(fn.length(), stats.getMax()); i <= max; i++) {
            if (scanfor.contains(fn.substring(0, i)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And got the following output:

```
2021-10-31T18:13:02.733379900Z
scanfor stats: IntSummaryStatistics{count=472948, sum=17972024, min=38, average=38.000000, max=38}
saved as: app.log
2021-10-31T18:53:39.232551600Z
Total time consumed in Minutes :40
```

Not much gain as compared to Update 2. Got pretty much same time elapsed.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca given that there are many files to check that doesn't seem like a good solution, as it needs a call to listFiles for each string that needs to be checked.

Comment: Fair enough. Close vote retracted.

Comment: Or getting all the files in a list of strings and then searching in it will be a better idea? I guess yes. That will be a better idea I think. Isn't it? Just now I got this idea.!

Comment: How big is the CSV file?

Comment: Csv has 800000 to 1.5 million records/lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File IO classes are not very quick when scanning huge filesystems. The call `dir.listFiles()` is - as you've noticed - very slow because it checks every name in the directory and instantiates 800,000 item array. The Files NIO package is much better at dealing with a big directory stream as the calls like `Files.find` return results very quickly when selecting files or folders.

So: if the CSV file is managable size to load in one step you could load the match strings first into a set and then do a (depth=1) directory scan to grab all the files - a simple predicate in the `find` skips past directories and checks for matches in the CSV.

```
try(var lines = Files.lines(csv)) {
    Set<String> scanfor = lines.map(line -> line.split(",", -1))
                               .filter(line -> line.length > 0)
                               .map(line -> line[0])
                               .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = scanfor.stream().mapToInt(String::length).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.println("scanfor stats: "+stats);

    try(var os   = Files.newBufferedWriter(out);
        var scan = Files.find(dir, 1, (p,a) -> !a.isDirectory() && !matches(p.getFileName().toString(), scanfor, stats))) {

        scan.map(Path::toString).forEach(s -> write(os, s));
    }
    System.out.println("saved as: "+out);
}
private static void write(BufferedWriter wr, String s) {
    try
    {
        wr.write(s);
        wr.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
private static boolean matches(String fn, Set<String> scanfor, IntSummaryStatistics stats) {
    // Can search by exact match in the set knowing the smallest/largest string of scanfor
    for (int i = stats.getMin(), max = Math.min(fn.length(), stats.getMax()); i <= max ; i++) {
        if (scanfor.contains(fn.substring(0, i)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT** I just re-read your question, it originally found the matches. You can decide to find files which do or don't match the CSV criteria with `matches` or `!matches` in the `find` predicate.

Comment: I tried it @DuncG. Please see my Update2 in the original post. For 200 files it works like a rocket. But for around 470k files, its taking forever.

Comment: If it writes a lot of lines: as Windows console is very slow try swap the System.out::println for writing line to some output file (or use redirection `java Blah > file.out` on the command line to rule out console speed issue.

Comment: I've changed matches to reduce comparisons and outputs to a file, but if that is no help you should go back to your original.

Comment: I added the outcome as Update 3, @DuncG.

Comment: What are the timings for the scanfor vs directory find, and what time does the original listFiles take?

Comment: Your solution was 2 mins faster than mine infact. Accepting it. However I got 6 mins faster solution using `FileVisitor`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `FileVisitor` like below to return a `List` of files:

```
public static List<String> getFilesList() {
    
    String dirPath = "W:\\ThePath\\ToThe\\Directory";
    
    List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileVisitor<Path> simpleFileVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path visitedFile, BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) throws IOException {
            filesList.add(visitedFile.getFileName().toString());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    };
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
    Path rootPath = fileSystem.getPath(dirPath);
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(rootPath, simpleFileVisitor);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filesList;
}
```

And I got the list back in 34.x minutes.